# Can util:RegistrySearch variables be used with an ExePackage's SourceFile in Burn?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

A program I'm developing requires OBS Studio, among other dependencies, to function. For convenience, I'm building a Burn bundle that will install each dependency in proper order before installing the main application.

Uninstalling is a problem. OBS has its own uninstall executable, and telling the Burn where that executable is has proven impossible. The install directory is clearly readable in the registry (OBS stores the install directory as a default value for the key):

```
<util:RegistrySearch
 Variable="OBS"
 Root="HKLM"
 Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\OBS Studio" />
```

But I cannot get the variable into the SourceFile of ExePackage that would use it during uninstallation. The following code has failed in my attempts:

```
<ExePackage Id="Uninstall_OBSStudio"
 SourceFile="!(wix.OBS)\uninstall.exe"
 DetectCondition="NOT OBS_exists"
 Cache="no"
 Compressed="no" />
```

Passing the variable as "[OBS]" has failed as well, being read as a literal string. Using the variable in conditions works without issue, but this won't go at all. I've even tried passing the value to a WixVariable, too:

```
<WixVariable Id="OBS_location" Value="[OBS]" />
```

To no avail. So far, it looks like util:RegistrySearch is locked out of some parts of Burn, for reasons I don't understand.

**What am I supposed to do to use a RegistrySearch variable within the SourceFile string?** Nothing I've done to format the data has worked. Can Burn even pass around data in the way I'm trying? Is there a better way to pull information from the registry for Burn chains?

I'm really hoping this just a syntactical issue. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The source file for all package types is resolved when you build the bundle. During runtime, Burn will hash the file to make sure it is running the same file that was specified at compile time.

There's a feature request in here somewhere, probably either a new package type for the installation framework that created that installer or the ability for an ExePackage to get its uninstall command from the registry. https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues